# How do I install userscript from the local machine with GreaseMonkey 1.12 (2013 autumn)?

Tags: firefox, localhost, local, greasemonkey, userscripts

I use Greasemonkey 1.12 with Firefox 24.
I have an userscript file on my computer. 
I cannot find the way to install my already written userscript from my local machine - how it is done?

There used to be some custom userscript window. Now it's integrated into Firefox's addons. Here I've tried the "get userscripts" link but it took me to the website.

I also tried the toolbar icon but I couldn't find a way to add an existing userscript. 
There is "manage userscripts" but it takes to the new integrated userscript list mentioned just before. I've tried to right-click the list but there was no context menu, no "add".

Then there is a "new userscript" button but it seems to be for creating userscripts from sratch.

Nevertheless, since this is the only place that seemed like I could manage to add an userscript from my local machine, I tried the "new userscript way".
I've tried to paste my userscript to the default in-browser editor from the clipboard.
It pastes but as soon as I press enter it deletes my script. Also after pasting the whole script is one line. I've tried to change the newlines from `LF` to `CRLF` but it didn't make any difference. In the end the script didn't work.

In the greasemonkey options there are a possibility to change the editor to something else... but is this *really* the way to add existing userscripts from my local computer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the way!

You are expected to *drag-n-drop* (from a file-manager window of your choice) the userscript file into the greasemonkey "manage userscripts" settings pane in `about:addons` in the browser. :)

(I could not drop them on the toolbar button, however.)